# How concerned should I be about checksum errors in a ZFS mirror?

Tags: zfs, freenas

I have a self-built FreeNAS system, which uses 4 HDD in one ZFS pool purely for storage, and 2 mirrored 16GB USB memory sticks in a ZFS mirror for booting from.  It is stable and has been running for around 8 months.  However, the overnight emails are usually along these lines:

> ```
> Checking status of zfs pools:
>  NAME           SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
>  freenas-boot  14.5G  1.67G  12.8G         -      -    11%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
>  volume1       7.25T   457G  6.80T         -     2%     6%  1.00x  ONLINE  /mnt
> ```
>
> pool: freenas-boot
>  state: ONLINE
> status: One or more devices has experienced an unrecoverable error.  An
>         attempt was made to correct the error.  Applications are unaffected.
> action: Determine if the device needs to be replaced, and clear the errors
>         using 'zpool clear' or replace the device with 'zpool replace'.
>    see: http://illumos.org/msg/ZFS-8000-9P
>   scan: scrub repaired 232K in 0h6m with 0 errors on Sun Oct 23 03:51:22 2016
> config:
>
> NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
>    freenas-boot                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
>      mirror-0                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
>        gptid/253f05a3-be26-11e5-8d9c-d05099c04470  ONLINE       0     0     1
>        gptid/879584e0-bfb0-11e5-ba20-d05099c04470  ONLINE       0     0     9
>
> errors: No known data errors

The checksum errors will occasionally increase, then when I perform a normal FreeNAS update, will all reset back to 0 again, whereupon the process will repeat, with the checksum errors creeping up now and again.

I've seen nothing to indicate that the HDDs themselves are having any faults, and I download the FreeNAS config to an external backup location when I make changes, so I should be able to reinstall on a new flash drive if necessary.

All that said, how concerned should I be about these checksum errors?

Comment: Relevant: [ZFS checksum errors, when do I replace the drive?](https://serverfault.com/q/789194/58408) on [sf].

Comment: Well, based on personal experience, I would say very concerned. Thank to checksum errors, my pool was lost as I was unable to import it.

Comment: @GGGuest I’d completely forgotten about this question. After asking it, I tried a different usb memory stick, only to quickly have the same issue.  I chose the enclosure and motherboard with future expansion in mind, so had plenty of free space for new internal drives - chucked in a couple of old ones to mirror the USBs, and haven’t looked back since.

Answer (score 2):

## Probable causes

These errors can have different sources, some popular include:

- Flaky connections or damaged cables
- Sudden power loss or forceful removal of devices
- Memory errors if using non-ECC RAM that is faulty

You can clear the errors with `zpool clear`, because the errors were few (instead of `too many errors`) and they did not affect the same blocks on each device. I suspect the FreeNAS upgrade also does this so it results in the situation you described.

## Possible solutions

I would do the following:

- Run memtest86+ overnight to rule out faults in the memory
- Disconnect and reconnect all cables, check for lose connections, if needed replace cables (they are cheap, so simply replacing them is quicker than troubleshooting)
- Try if running with an UPS makes a difference if you live in an area with unstable energy supply (brown-outs are a thing in some parts of the USA, I've read)
- Test if the USB port/controller is at fault by using a different one, or a PCIe adaptor card (quite cheap)
- Try to use another type of USB sticks, I've had good experiences with SLC-based USB3 sticks (only checksum errors were on removal or blackout)